# React to FieldValidations and form submissions

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-applications

I have an ASP.NET Web Application and in there i have a `Form` where certain `TextBoxes` have a `FieldValidator` attached to them.

At the end of the form i have a typical submit button which submits the form when pressed.

Everything works fine so far. Also the validators are triggered when certain fields are left empty.

But it can take some time for the page to reload with new data when a user submits the form. So what i want to do is to add a "spinner" next to the Submit button. So the user knows it is currently working on its request.

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('.spinner').show();
    });
});
```

This also works fine so far. Until a user tries to submit a form with an invalid field. Then the spinner is showing but the form didn't really submit.

Is there a way i can respond to that? So i can hide the spinner again when ASP.NET triggers a client sided validation message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Page_IsValid` variable for that in your Javascript code which should be available by default. So in your case you can simply do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            // Do your thing...
        }
    });
});
```